# Post Request from my website not working in Heroku App NodeJS but from localhost it is working

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

In localhost I am making post request to my Nodejs App deployed on Heroku and it's working very well .But from my website domain it's not .
Get request are working from the website domain. I enabled Cors . I am using Angular in the client side

```
test.js
router.post('/ptest', (req, res) => {


res.send( "200");


});
```

app.js

```
    var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var app = express();


var testRouter = require('./routes/test');


app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/test', testRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    // set locals, only providing error in development
    res.locals.message = err.message;
    res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

    // render the error page
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: What's the error in the console?

Comment: No error in the console

Comment: On Heroku CLI too?

Comment: No on Heroku too

Comment: Did you set all the env variables in the Heroku environment too as you might have used some with the local setup?

Comment: Like the database related credentials which might be hosted somewhere on the cloud

Comment: Most probably the error is somewhere around database only because you mentioned that get request is working perfectly fine for you

Comment: I did'nt configure env variables

Comment: That's strange not having error both on console and on Heroku and still not working

Comment: I found ! The error was on my client side ajax request not corrects

Comment: That's great then!